# Fatal Error: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm very very new to android programming and while trying to run this simple program I get the error: `"Unfortunately your app stopped"`.

So I went and looked in the **Logcat** file and this is where, I think, the problem is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                   Process:  org.example.tictactoe, PID: 3202
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.tictactoe/org.example.tictactoe.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

But looking at my files I don't see where It's missing.

This are the files .xml which I used:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false"
tools:context=".TicTacToeActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
    android:name="org.example.tictactoe.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
  android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_high"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="@dimen/menu_padding"
  tools:context=".TicTacToeActivity">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/menu_space"
    android:text="@string/long_app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/continue_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_button_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/menu_button_padding"
    android:text="@string/continue_label"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/new_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_button_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/menu_button_padding"
    android:text="@string/new_game_label"
    />

     <Button
     android:id="@+id/about_button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_button_margin"
     android:padding="@dimen/menu_button_padding"
     android:text="@string/about_label"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

**menu_background**:

```
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
       android:width="@dimen/stroke_width"
       android:color="@color/border_color"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/field_color"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius"/>
</shape>
```

I cannot find where the layout_width attribute is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are blank spaces in your layout. For example, in `fragment_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android "
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools "
```

Use Find and Replace for `"` or  in your layout.

---

UPDATE

You have another error in the following xml:

You can't use `class="org.example.tictactoe.MainFragment"`. But you need to use `android:name` attribute. So, it should be:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
    android:name="org.example.tictactoe.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"/>
```

Found another problem in your xml code. Use `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` instead of `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android"`.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted the code and edited my question, but I still get the same damned error when I run the app.

Comment: @IDK: Found another error in your code. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Ok so, I modified the code and edited my question... but still:         --------- beginning of crash
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: org.example.tictactoe, PID: 3110
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.tictactoe/org.example.tictactoe.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

Comment: That's is really an annoying problem. You can try to recreate the layout from scratch without copy-pasting your xml code. This is the better way instead wasting your precious time searching for the problem.

Comment: @IDK: Found another problem in your xml code. Use `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` instead of `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android"`

Comment: Finally, the problem is solved. Congratulations! You're very welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in `"wrap_content "` for `layout_width` and `layout_height` in `MainFragment`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know that, however  after removing the spaces, the same error still appears...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:layout_gravity="@layout/fragment_main"` from `activity_main.xml`

`android:layout_gravity` requires specific parameters [android:layout_gravity Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity)

[Fragments reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer you were right, I changed it and edited my question  but still, when running I get the same damned error.